# Проблема с добавлением нового свойства товара в 1С Битрикс Интернет магазин

Tags: битрикс, 1с, интернет-магазин

При добавлении нового свойства товара на стороне клиента это свойство не отображается. На текущий момент возможно только вручную включить отображение этого свойства таким образом https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/166748/blog/12875/  . Данный способ крайне неудобен так как при выгрузке большого количества новых свойств товара вручную проделать сами понимаете.... Есть ли возможность решить вопрос по другому? Буду благодарен за любую наводку.

Comment: А что вы хотите делать вручную?

Comment: в том то и дело что вручную (редактирование шаблон кампонента) для большого  количество новый свойств крайне не удобно. Поэтому и хотелось узнать есть ли другие способы

Comment: так вы один раз редактируете, комментируете код, который скрывает свойства типа файл 'F' , в шаблоне вы комментируете один раз http://prntscr.com/t18y9m